# ProtoEnum attribute usage for renaming conflicting default values

Tags: c#, c++, .net, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am attempting to generate c++ protobuf classes from a large c# .net codebase. The enumeration 'NotSet' is used as a default value in many enum declarations throughout, so I have used the ProtoEnum attribute to provide a different name for exporting where conflicts have arisen. However I have found that where my exported .proto file has classes with one of these enums as a member its default value still uses the orginal name, and protoc then fails to produce C++ files without correction.

Using the following example,

```
[DataContract]
[ProtoContract]
public enum MyEnum
{
    [EnumMember]
    [ProtoEnum(Name = "MyEnum_NotSet", Value=0)]
    NotSet,

    SomeValue,   
 
    AndSoOn
}
```

In a class I need to export the enumeration appears as a member I wish to export.

```
[ProtoContract]
public class MyClass
{
    [DataMember]
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    private MyEnum m_myEnum;
}
```

However in the exported .proto file, this class ends up with the original enum name as its default value...

```
syntax = "proto2";

enum MyEnum {
   MyEnum_NotSet = 0;
   SomeValue= 1;
   AndSoOn= 2;
}

message MyClass{
   optional MyEnum m_myEnum= 1 [default = NotSet];
}
```

Using protoc to generate c++ files from this fails - Enum type "MyEnum" has no value named "NotSet".

Is there some step I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a bug in protobuf-net; I've fixed in [in this commit](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/commit/b6d06456ba02d09569f82b9531bfe2b1645249dd), which not yet available in nuget - but note that this will apply in v3 only (I haven't back-ported the fix to the v2 branch).

Comment: Thanks Marc, that's good to know. I can fix this up manually for the time being.